# Override NG in angular Js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng

I know this question seems to be vague initially but I want to override the ng with anything else may be my name.

We can override `$` of jquery,

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
```

we can override other things by specifying it to variable like

```
var hello=$http;
```

And use hello as $http in the whole program.

So my simple question is can we override ng and use something else in html.

No  performance issue just curious to know is there anyway to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It's a little old, but there is a solution over here: http://www.mattburkedev.com/multiple-angular-versions-on-the-same-page/

Yes it's possible. Small example using angular as something else and the orignal angular global is now in existingWindowDotAngular.

```
var existingWindowDotAngular = window.angular;
var angular = 'whatever';
```

You can't override AngularJS built-in directives. However, you can define multiple directives with the same name and have them executed against the same element. By assigning appropriate priority to your directive, you can then control whether your directive runs before or after a built-in directive.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it with example i read the tutorial but still didn't get it how to override. ng

Comment: Added a small example.

Comment: pal i agree it will change the word angular to something else but what about ng-click,ng-controller..etc.I am talking about "ng" specifically.
But thanks for your effort.

Comment: Ah you can't override AngularJS built-in directives. However, you can define multiple directives with the same name and have them executed against the same element. By assigning appropriate priority to your directive, you can then control whether your directive runs before or after a built-in directive.